# Couchbase.exceptions._TimeoutError while trying to retrieve the document information

Tags: python, database, couchbase

I am using python 3 with couchbase client. I have 461378 records in couchbase bucket and RAM used/quota is 3.77GB / 5.78GB. I am trying to retrieve the document by using the following code:

```
    list_of_rows = []
    for idx, product_details in enumerate(CouchRepo.get_product_details_iterator()):
        list_of_rows.append(get_required_dict_for_df(product_details["data"]))
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
in __iter__
    raw_rows = self.raw.fetch(self._mres)
couchbase.exceptions._TimeoutError_0x17 (generated, catch TimeoutError): <RC=0x17[Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the timeout], HTTP Request failed. Examine 'objextra' for full result, Results=1, C Source=(src/http.c,144), OBJ=ViewResult<rc=0x17[Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the timeout], value=None, http_status=0, tracing_context=0, tracing_output=None>, Tracing Output={":nokey:0": null}>
```

Basically inside code,

```
  while self._do_iter:
     raw_rows = self.raw.fetch(self._mres)
     for row in self._process_payload(raw_rows):
         yield row
```

I have tried setting a different operation_timeout but getting the same error. I also checked how can I allocate more RAM to bucket or node but not getting any solution. I have gone through the following links but didn't find any implementation details.

https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/current/client-settings.html

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/sizing-general.html

How can I retrieve records info, also the number of records will increase in the future.